# How can I call the freshest implementation of an R function during package development?

Tags: r

Setup:

- I'm editting the body of a function `foo.bar()`in my own package `MyPkg`.
- I launch an R session in the root of the package (where `DESCRIPTION` sits).
- For good measure, I start cleanly

  devtools::reload()
- To confirm which version of `foo.bar` in `MyPkg` I'd be running I call:

  find("foo.bar")

and get:

```
[1] ".GlobalEnv"
```

This means that when I call `foo.bar` I'd be calling the function installed for my user account.

It's obscure to me how `MyPkg` got installed for my user account (or why it's necessary), possibly just calling `devtools::reload()` or `devtools::test()` did that.

How do I specify that I'd like to call the freshest version of a given function, from the current `<root>/R` folder?

Comment: `devtools::load_all()` should do the trick.

Comment: @clemens After modifying a function `foo.bar` in either `MyPkg/R` or in `MyPkg/tests/testthat`, `find("foo.bar")` returns two places (`[1] ".GlobalEnv" "package:MyPkg"`). Now calling `foo.bar()` picks up the stale version. Any suggestions to remove the one in ".GlobalEnv"? (should it be there in the first place?)

Comment: Use `rm(foo.bar)`

Comment: @clemens Thanks. Please add as an answer so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `load_all()` from `devtools` which loads a package that's in development and allows you to use it (e.g. its functions) as if it was installed and loaded.

If your current working directory is the root of your package, just type

```
devtools::load_all()
```

If the root is not in your current working directory, pass the absolute path to the root as an argument:

```
devtools::load_all('/absolute/path/to/MyPkg')
```

To remove functions that you have defined in your global environment, use `rm()`, e.g. `rm(foo.bar)`