# Origin of source code caching when writing an R package

Tags: r, r-package

Even though I [duly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49283531/9295807) `setwd()` (within an R session running in an Emacs/ESS buffer) to the root of my R package and run `devtools::load_all()` there, when I call a function I find that I am running a version of the function that no longer exists in the present R package. Running `rm(<function_name>)`, followed by `source`-ing the relevant file, do not help.

*Might I perhaps be running a version of the package that I inadvertently installed?*, I ask myself. I run [`lapply(.libPaths(), dir)`](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/package.html#package) to answer, but my package does not appear.

What is happening? Where/how is this caching happening?

**Update**

Running

```
rm(list=ls())
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8813753/9295807) solved the problem. Although it's not clear what the problem might have been in the first place. An explanation is very welcome.

Comment: There's not really enough here to tell what's going on. Some sort of [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Or show exactly what you are seeing in the console that makes the problem more clear. Show the code you are running.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you are doing but `setwd()` has no place in package code.

Comment: Also run `search()` and maybe `find(your_function)` to see what's on your search tree and where the function is being found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R caches your global environment in a file `.Rdata`. Delete it and start a new session.