# R packages: "Error: object 'compute' not found whilst loading namespace .."

Tags: r, r-package, r-devtools

My directory structure is as follows:

```
c:/Users/bob/MyPackageName
c:/Users/bob/MyPackageName/R
c:/Users/bob/MyPackageName/tests
c:/Users/bob/MyPackageName/tests/testthat
```

My development session normally consists of starting an R session in the package root (`c:/Users/bob/MyPackageName`), and running

```
devtools::load_all()
devtools::test()
```

followed by alternating the addition of little bits in `MyPackageName/tests/testthat/mytest.R` and in `MyPackageName/R/mycode.R`.

When starting a session returns

```
Loading MyPackageName
Error: object 'compute' not found whilst loading namespace 'MyPackageName'
```

I try:

1. Calling an [explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49283531/9295807) `devtools::load_all("c:/Users/bob/MyPackageName")`
2. Searching for an errant instance of `compute` (package required, function name, anything..). But all is good.
3. [Clearing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8813753/9295807) some caches, `rm(list=ls())`.
4. Calling a localized `devtools::load_all()` from a session in `c:/Users/bob/MyPackageName/tests/testthat` and another in `c:/Users/bob/MyPackageName/tests/testthat`.
5. Regenerating the documentation through `devtools::document()`, lest some corruption in those has gone awry.
6. Delete `MyPackageName/.RData` and `MyPackageName/.Rhistory`.

But nothing. I still get `Error: object 'compute' not found whilst loading namespace 'MyPackageName'`

What else can I try? For example, what is the pre-Devtools method of "loading all"? What is "object 'compute'"?

When I start an R session outside of the package directory, all is well. Hence my R setup is fine; this question is in the context of writing an R package.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a work-around. Perhaps you can give it a try.

I have encountered similar error `Error: object 'compute' not found whilst ...` when I rebuilt a package (R version 3.5.0, roxygen2 version 3.5.0).

I wound up with manually removing the first row `S3method(compute,...)` in `NAMESPACE` to get the package rebuilt.

Comment: Very interesting. Your hint had not solved my problem then, but it does solve this https://stackoverflow.com/q/50728217/9295807 question.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the function names but this could be an issue since ROxygen >3 now uses `@export` for both S3 objects and functions. Therefore, if you have a function using dots e.g. `compute.something.cool()` and you use ROxygen's `#' @export`, it might be inferring that it is a S3 object rather than a function.

This is described in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594507/exporting-non-s3-methods-with-dots-in-the-name-using-roxygen2-v4) but in short explicitly name your function with the export call:

```
#' @export compute.something.cool
```

This approach will mean you can still use `devtools::document()` to keep your NAMESPACE updated without having to manually do it. A note, that [Bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org/) do not permit packages to use dot naming conventions, probably for this very reason so it might be worth avoiding this in the future.