# "object not found" during package build/install

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I'm at a loss to debug building/installing a package. Building a package "MyProjekt" through

```
> devtools::build("MyProjekt")
```

works fine, even though

```
> devtools::document()
Updating MyProjekt documentation
Loading MyProjekt
Error: object 'rank' not found whilst loading namespace 'MyProjekt'
```

fails.

Attempting to install the built (pure R) package

```
> install.packages(pkgs="./MyProjekt.tar.gz")
...
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'MyProjekt':
 object 'rank' not found whilst loading namespace 'MyProjekt'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
...
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
```

also fails.

Unfortunately the term 'rank' is a common term in my domain and I have hundreds of hits when searching in my files for that term.

How might I start a systematic way to hunt this bug down?

Answer (score 0):

The toolchain mistakenly generates S3method(...) in the NAMESPACE file.

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50511076/9295807) answer and edit the NAMESPACE file by hand. Replace occurrences of `S3method(f)` with `export(f)`.

I'm not certain this is repeatable. The generated files appear to be not just written, but also read during a subsequent package build (by devtools? by roxygen2?). Add your comments if this works/does not work for you.